# Gradle build - Cannot allocate memory

Tags: java, gradle, build

Works on Windows 7 flawlessly, but on ubuntu 12.04 get the error.
I'm really no ideas what it's wrong with it.
Please help
See the stacktrace below with some configuration and version notes

http://pastebin.com/uwjLV1G6

Comment: Dies it work if you don't muck around with the `-Xmx` memory settings?

Comment: no, it doesn't in both cases

Comment: Is the box running something else that's taking all the memory?

Comment: No, I check the "free -m" during the build process and got http://pastebin.com/PvkFag8V

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the location where java code was. I use vagrant to setup the local dev environment and share my code from host windows machine to guest linux.
problem was occured during build java with help of gradle on vagrant guest.
to solve this issue I temporary moved required java code in other location on vagrant guest and it works perfectly.
thanks for the help @tim-yates!